# Yii2 - Export Kartik-v

Tags: yii, yii2, kartik-v

I have many tables that can be displayed in Yii2. One of them is like this:

[image]

We can download the table by clicking download button. Many tables can be download one by one. One table can only download its table. Actually, I want all of tables can be downloaded in one file. What I want to ask: Is there any way to download all of the tables and make them on one document?

Here is my view code:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Model;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\Temppelamarmagisterjk */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan Jenis Kelamin');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="tempppelamarmagisterjk-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <!--<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Jumlah Pelamar Magister'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?> -->
    </p>
    <?php
        $gridColumns =[
            'TahunDaftar',
            'Lakilaki',
            'Perempuan',
            'TidakDiketahui',
            'Total'
        ];

        //Renders a export dropdown menu
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            ]);
    ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'TahunDaftar',
            'Lakilaki',
            'Perempuan',
            'TidakDiketahui',
            'Total',

            ////['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you need to use some custom solution because it looks like Kartik is not supporting something like this.

Comment: Custom solution like what? Could you please give me the link about tutorial of that problem? @Bizley

Comment: I don't know any tutorial for such a case.

Comment: You could use a custom solution like Bizley said, make your own excel export: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-phpexcel/